# displaying object in the view using knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

i need help, i have action that return object(JSON format, i use this approche: "http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Build-truly-RESTful-API-194a6253"), here is the object that i return from action (Index of DashboardController) :

```
   var model = new DashboardHomeModel()
        {                
            CurrentCompaigns = .....................,
            BuzzLeaderCompaigns = ..................,            
            BuzzCompaignByInterest =  ..................
        };
    return View(model);
```

first i want to display BuzzLeaderCompaigns(it is a ICollection of Compaign) of my model, and here is my view :

```
               <h3>My Compaign</h3>
       <table>
            <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th>Compaign Name</th><th>Compaign Description</th><th>End Date</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
           <tbody data-bind="foreach: BuzzLeaderCompaigns">
             <tr>
               <td data-bind="text: Name" ></td>            
                <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: EndDate"></td>
              </tr>       
          </tbody>
       </table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      function Compaign(data) {
           this.BuzzCompaignId = ko.observable(data.BuzzCompaignId);
           this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
           this.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
           this.EndDate = ko.observable(data.EndDate);
      }

      function DashboardViewModel() {
           var self = this;
           self.BuzzLeaderCompaigns = ko.observableArray([]);      
           self.CurrentCompaigns = ko.observableArray([]);
           self.BuzzCompaignByInterest = ko.observableArray([]);
        // Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
        $.getJSON("/Dashboard/Index", function (Data) {
              var mappedData = $.map(Data, function() { return   } ) ;
      });

      } 
     ko.applyBindings(new DashboardViewModel());

    </script>
```

how can i bind my data to my viewmodel(when i get data with $.getJSON) and then my view

Answer (score 1):

Assuming /Dashboard/Index returns the CurrentCompaigns, change this:

```
$.getJSON("/Dashboard/Index", function (Data) {
    var mappedData = $.map(Data, function() { return   } ) ;
});
```

To this:

```
$.getJSON("/Dashboard/Index", function (Data) {
    var mappedData = $.map(Data, function(item) { return new Compaign(item) });
    self.CurrentCompaigns(mappedData);
});
```

You should consider Arbiter's advice, however; /Dashboard/Index sounds like an action method that should return a view, and not a JSON action method. You could either have three separate JSON methods for your three observableArrays, or you could have a single method that returns all the "Compaigns" and then use ko.utils.arrayFilter to filter and assign values to your three arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that will put you on the right track:

- If your view (cshtml) is called "Index" then you should create a different action on your controller to return your json.
- Instead of returning `View(model);` you should have your new action return `Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` to have the action return JSON (instead of HTML). Your existing action (Index) should return a model-less view, i.e. `return View();`
- Change the path of your `getJSON` to use the new path, i.e.:

  $.getJSON("/Dashboard/GetCampaign", function (Data) {
      *Code which populates your viewmodel*
  );

Comment: index action can return JSON , i use this api : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Build-truly-RESTful-API-194a6253 and then there is annotation([EnableJson]) above index() ;

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your view model directly to Json string also with some server side code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
        // this example is using Json.Net  
        var model = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()));
        // wrapper contains additional methods and logic 
        // knockout mapping plugin is used to convert json objects to observable objects
        var wrapper = new ViewModelWrapper(ko.mapping.fromJS(model));           
        ko.applyBindings(wrapper);
  </script>
```